# Gradle task to create fat runnable jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java application with Main class which has dependencies to couple of other library jars. I need to create a runnable jar in gradle with all dependant libraries copied to the jar. The gradle plugin "application" or "java" does not provide this. I am using latest gradle version 6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this by creating a task which does the following things

- Update manifest file with the Main-Class attributes
- Copy all compile time dependencies to the jar task

  ```
  plugins {
    id 'application'
  }    
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    //jcenter()
  }    
  dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20200518'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
   }    
   task fatJar(type: Jar) {

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.gradle.App'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } with jar
  }
  ```

More details can be read in this article [A simple java project with Gradle](https://jafarmlp.medium.com/a-simple-java-project-with-gradle-2c323ae0e43d)